# I want to add a delay in a way, on button click update a label, sleep for few seconds and then update other labels

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, event-dispatch-thread, thread-sleep

This is the listener for the button.

```
 dice.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           String randomNum = String.valueOf(randomNumber);
           rand.setText(" Move forward "+randomNum+" boxes");  //rand is a label 
           try {
                    Thread.sleep(6000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
               } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                         Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
               }
           //here some handling with randomNumber
              Position[playerTurn].setText(posi);
     } //end of actionlistener
```

I want to add sleep between `rand.setText` and `Position[playerTurn].setText` but it is not working as expected. It first waits then immediately set both labels which I don't want.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: (Y) I find it helpful ! Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because repaint hasn't been called yet. So in the background you are changing the rand text, it waits 6 seconds, then it will set the Position text. But there is no repaint in between, so they will draw at the same time.

```
    dice.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {     
            String randomNum = String.valueOf(randomNumber);

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(6000);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ie){}

                    Position[playerTurn].setText(posi);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

This will start a new Thread,  so that will allow the first label to be repainted immediately in your main AWT thread, then you have an offshoot thread here that will fire off in 6 seconds. You will have to determine what you want to do if an exception is caught in the Runnable though.

### EDIT

Noticed that you are declaring the string inside the listener, which will be an issue for this code. You will need to declare it as final or as an instance variable.

Comment: My pleasure! I didn't know how to do this before answering the question, but I knew what the problem was. So thank you for getting me look into it!

Answer (score 0):

You may use Thread.sleep(milliseconds); surrounded by try catch statement.
but the better way is to use a thread.
Some sample code is here this will help you out.

```
//declare a globalcounter and boolean like this;
private int counttalk=0;
private boolean mySpeakanim=false;
```

call this method in oncreate of your code;

```
speakAnim();
```

//where you want to start animation for your label do this

```
countalk=0;
mySpeakanim=true;



private void speakAnim() {
    // gonelayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    Handler handler1 = new Handler();

    handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (mySpeakAnim) {
                Log.d("SpeakAnim", "SpeakAnim");
                counttalk += 1;
                if (counttalk == 1) {
                    label.setText("Your Label1");
                } else if (counttalk == 2) {
                    label.setText("Your Label2");

                } else if (counttalk == 3) {
                    label.setText("Your Label3");

                } else if (counttalk == 4) {
                    label.setText("Your Label4");
                    counttalk = 0;
                }

            }

            speakAnim();
        }
    }, 100L);

}
```

you can change thread duration from 100L and counter for animation according to your need.

Comment: just make the boolean mySpeakAnim false where you want to stop animation.

Answer (score 0):

Two methods of the EventQueue class, invokeLater and invokeAndWait, are provided for the purpose of invoking later.

```
package com.makesh.sandbox;

import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class HelloWorldSwing implements ActionListener {

    private Button button;
    private JLabel delayedLabel;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPanel myPanel;

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
        frame.getContentPane().setSize(800,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setTitle("My Program");

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("My Program"));

        myPanel = new JPanel();
        myPanel.setOpaque(true);
        myPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Login"));
        myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 20, 20));

        button = new Button(" Click Me please to display text after timer sleep");
        delayedLabel = new JLabel("Label 2");

        myPanel.add(button);
        myPanel.add(delayedLabel);

        contentPane.add(myPanel);
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        button.addActionListener(this);

        // Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(6000); // 1000 milliseconds is one second.
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Worker());
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    private final class Worker implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(600);
                delayedLabel.setText(" Modified label 2 after sleep");
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                HelloWorldSwing helloWorldSwing = new HelloWorldSwing();
                helloWorldSwing.createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```